# Using while to iterate through a list with a condition?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am trying to iterate through a list of prime numbers, but I want to stop when I hit a certain limit.

```
def primetest(number,primelst):
    limit = int(round(sqrt(number),0)+1)
    while prime in primelst < limit:
        if (number % prime) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

As a FOR statement this works:

```
def primetest(number,primelst):
    limit = int(round(sqrt(number),0)+1)
    for prime in primelst:
        if (number % prime) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

But this is slow because it iterates through **all** the primes, where I want the iteration to stop when it hits the limit. So a `while` statement seems a better choice, but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a check in the body of the loop:

```
for prime in primelst:
    if prime > limit:
        break
    # ...
```

**Update**: I originally suggested using `enumerate`, but I see that you actually want to stop the loop when the prime number is larger than `limit`.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using while, there is this way of looping what might work in your case:

```
def primetest(number,primelst):
    i=0
    limit = int(round(sqrt(number),0)+1)
    while primelst[i] < limit:
        if (number % primelst[i]) == 0:
            return False
        i=i+1
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- but since my list of primes gets added to based on the results of this function, incrementing the index and then testing the primelst[i] generates an "out of range" error.